# Boolean loop combined with JOptionPane Java

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

I would love to share my code. But in my university the code gets tested for "cheating".

But here is my code in simplier form.

```
public static String readin() {
    boolean error = false;
    do {
        string stringin;
        stringin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a number");
        switch (stringin.length()) {
            case 0:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Please repeat");
                error = true;

            case 1:
                return stringin;
        }
        return null;
    } while (error == true);
}
```

This Code is really in it's simpliest form. I know that for this case it would be smarter to set the while to JOptionPane is empty or something. Since in my code are like 12 different error cases. I want to use the boolean. Please: the return null will never occur in the real code.

But the real problem I have: It works perfectly fine besides: if he repeats the loop he doesn't give me the chance to type a new stringin in. 
How can i do this?

Also I am sorry for my faults in english.

EDIT:
All your helps fixed my problems! Thank you very much! I love this forum!

Comment: Yo have no break statement in your case 0: block so flow falls though to the case 1: block and returns out of your routine, so no looping is possible.

Comment: also move your return null to after the while (error == true) and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **break** before `case 1` (@Tuxxy_Thang) and remove `return null;` before `while (error);` and put after.

```
public static String readin(){
    boolean error=false;
    do{ 
        string stringin;
        stringin=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter a number");
        switch (stringin.length()){
            case 0: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Please repeat");
                error=true;
                break;
            case 1: return stringin;
        } 
    } while (error);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Still needs the return after the while to compile

Comment: Yep that works but the whole method is kind of over complicated and frought with possibilities of implementation errors imho

Comment: You're right, but I prefer to keep the original algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to check for while condition as you wanted the user to repeat again.Return only if you have the right value else ask again

```
 public static String readin() {
        while (true) {
            String stringin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a number");
            switch (stringin.length()) {
                case 0:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Please repeat");
                    break;//is important in switch cases
                case 1:
                    return stringin;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons:

- The `return null` should be moved to end.
- There should be a `break` statement at the end of the first case

I have given the modified code and it repeats the loop if the user does not enter anything for the JOptionPane:

```
public static String readin() {
    boolean error = false;
    do {
        String stringin;
        stringin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please enter a number");
        switch (stringin.length()) {
        case 0:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Please repeat");
            error = true;
            break;                       // **added**
        case 1:
            return stringin;
        }
    } while (error == true);
    return null; // Moved here. It will return if user entered more than 1 letter.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a simple job hard, use Java classes properly and you will have an easier time of things

```
public static String readin()
{
    Boolean gettingNumber = true;
    String stringin = null;

    while (gettingNumber)
    {
        stringin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a number");

        try
        {
            Integer number = Integer.parseInt(stringin);
            gettingNumber = false;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException exception)
        {
            // no need to do anything
        }

    }

    System.out.println("returning [" + stringin + "]");
    return(stringin);
}
```

I added this because I deduced that you are asking the user to input a number but your code would only allow the user ot enter any single character regardless of whether it is a valid digit or not and that is what you would return form your original method.

Comment: You can shorten this by adding a return statement in the try block. I did not do this because I hate returning anywhere in code, imho there shold only be 1 retrun at teh end of a method.